# Is there a preferred way to access Java object fields from native (C) code?

Tags: java, performance, java-native-interface

I am using an embedded JVM to call new Java code from a legacy application written in C.  I've written an adapter layer in Java to simplify the API as much as possible, but it still has to return POD objects with String and int fields through the JNI to the C code.  I am wondering whether there is a recommended way for the C code to access object fields.

Suppose I have a Java class:

```
class Pod {
    ...
    final int foobar;
    ...
    int getFoobar() { return foobar; }
    ...
}
```

Should I call the getFoobar() accessor method?

```
static jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "my/package/Pod");
static jmethodID getFoobar_id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class, getFoobar, "()I");

jobject pod = ...;
jint foobar = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, pod, getFoobar_id);
```

Or should I directly access the foobar field?

```
static jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "my/package/Pod");
static jfieldID foobar_field_id = (*env)->GetFieldId(env, class, "foobar", "I");

jobject pod = ...;
jint foobar = (*env)->GetIntField(env, pod, foobar_field_id);
```

I can experiment to find out whether one way performs better than the other, but I was wondering whether there is any accepted, industry-standard practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are valid.  I would use the following rule to decide which to use: If, instead of using C, I were using java to implement the activities the legacy application is doing, would I use `getFoobar()` or `foobar`?  Write what you want to say, not what you think the computer needs to hear to do it.

Generally speaking, it seems like legacy code is using Pod, rather than being part of the Pod API, so I would expect it to use the "public" interface for Pod.  Usually that means members like `getFoobar()`, but since your particular example is a `final int`, it isn't as clear.

`GetIntField` will outperform `CallIntMethod` if performance is your greatest concern.

Comment: That's about what I expected to hear.  The Pod class is part of a Facade that I wrote to simplify the Java<=>C interface for this particular application.  It can be whatever I need it to be.